# How to add to options hash only if a condition is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails project I have this mailer class:

```
class ProjectMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def send_project_link(delivery)
    @delivery = delivery
    mail(:from     => @delivery.sender_email, 
         :to       => @delivery.recipient_email, 
         :bcc      => [@delivery.sender_email],
         :subject  => @delivery.subject)
  end

end
```

What is the cleanest way to either include or not include the key/value pair `:bcc` in the hash, depending on whether `true` or `false` is given?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by not including the `:bcc` value? Do you want a `nil` value for it, or do you want the key `:bcc` to be absent as well? And by whatever that is "passed into the send_project_link() method as a parameter", do you simply mean `delivery`?

Comment: @sawa: OK, I tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not include the `:bcc` key in the options, you could do this:

```
class ProjectMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_project_link(delivery, send_with_bcc=false)
    @delivery = delivery
    mail_options = {
      :from     => @delivery.sender_email, 
      :to       => @delivery.recipient_email, 
      :subject  => @delivery.subject
    }  
    mail_options[:bcc] = [@delivery.sender_email] if send_with_bcc
    mail(mail_options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mail(
  {
    from:    @delivery.sender_email, 
    to:      @delivery.recipient_email, 
    subject: @delivery.subject,
  }
  .tap{|h| h[:bcc] = [@delivery.sender_email] if @delivery}
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `tap` method is too advanced for me now. Will keep it in mind for next time, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this...

```
def send_project_link(delivery. bcc? = false)
  @delivery = delivery
  mail_options = {:from     => @delivery.sender_email, 
                  :to       => @delivery.recipient_email, 
                  :subject  => @delivery.subject
                 }
  mail_options[:bcc] = [@delivery.sender_email] if bcc?
  mail mail_options
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is practically the same as Sam's solution.